# context.strokeText using for

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to get an amount of numbers on my canvas. My code is being repeated using eventhandlers on my timer.

For every 5 seconds that pass, I want to add another number on my canvas. It is used for a flowing timeline underneath my graph.

The forloop itself works fine, but every time it runs, it overwrites the current stroked-text.
Here is the for;

```
           pos = (time * (360 / 60) - 360); // calculate position in graph
            var t = new Array(); // array of numbers
            var x = new Array(); // array of xPos
            var y = new Array(); // array of yPos
            // new time number, position + distance to next number for each 5 seconds + compensation(60), yPos
            for (var i = 0 ; i < add / 5; i++) { // add / 5 is the count of numbers to add
                t[i] = add + 35;
                x[i] = -pos + (30 * (add / 5) + 60); // positions the number 30px next to the number before it.
                y[i] = 330;
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
                ctx.strokeText(t[i], x[i], y[i]);  // draws the number
            }
            //this line here gives back the exact same result as the code above.
            //ctx.strokeText((add + 35).toString(), -pos + (30 * (add / 5) + 60), 330);
```

I can't call new on ctx... and this just overwrites the old stroke..
It is currently live here:
http://worms.azurewebsites.net/#
If you press the play-button you'll see the blue bar move to 30, from here on the numbers should be moving to the left. This is somewhat working(shocking start) but if you wait a couple of seconds you can see the new numbers appearing and disappearing.

I just can't figure out a way to add an extra number to the canvas..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x[i] = -pos + (30 * (add / 5) + 60); // positions the number 30px next to the number before`

This calculation can't be right -- it doesn't depend on `i` (or any other variable that changes during the course of the loop) at all, so you're just drawing the same thing in the same place `add / 5` times over. Same for `t[i]` in the line above it. Maybe you mean something like this?

```
t[i] = add + 35 + 30 * i; // Just guessing here on how i and t relate...
x[i] = -pos + (30 * i + 60);
```

Comment: Fixed major part of it. Just need to do some additional tweaking, but fixed the problem itself. Thanks alot!